# Controls in f1 2015

Tags: keyboard, mouse, f1-2015

Is there a mouse control available in f1 2015? Is it going to be available in 2016? I tried project cars a few months ago. The mouse control made the car more controllable than keyboard but I couldn't control formula a cars without assists as I couldn't control the amount of throttle which always resulted in me spinning of due to wheelspin. Is it same for f1 2015/16? I know that a cheap controller might make things better but I am not in a position to buy one now (my parents agree to buy me games but not controllers, dunno why).

**tldr;** Is mouse control available in f1 2015? Are the cars controllable (in terms of wheelspin) without assists?

Comment: If 2016 is not out yet, I would remove that portion of your question(s). Questions regarding unreleased content are off-topic here.